# How to submit Form using Ajax in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, forms

I am trying to submit a HTML `Form` using `Ajax`, But I am not getting any alert success or failure.

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" class="needs-validation" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="/upload/" id="fupload">

    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="data_files" name="data_files" multiple required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="data_files">Choose files</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Upload files</button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#fupload');
    frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Form Submitted');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('Form submission failed');
            }
        });
        return false;
     });
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse()
```

Any guesses why it doesn't work

Comment: Try removing `return false;` at AJAX function and see if that work or not?

Comment: I think the issue is `action='/upload/'` which will be looking for `upload` in `urls.py`.  You need it to run the javascript and it is never getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following:

- Remove the `action`.
- Change the button to `type="button"` and add an event listener

  ```
  <form method="post" class="needs-validation" id="fupload">

      <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="data_files" name="data_files" multiple required>
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="data_files">Choose files</label>
      </div>

      <button type="button" id="upload-files-btn">Upload files</button>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var frm = $('#fupload');
      var btn = $('#upload-files-btn');
      btn.bind('click', handleClick);
      var formData = new FormData(); // Use FormData instead
      formData.append('file', frm.files[0], frm.files[0].name) // The first argument is the 'key' of the form data so change it to whatever works.
      var handleClick = function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: '/upload/',
              data: formData,
              contentType: false,  // add this to indicate 'multipart/form-data'
              success: function (data) {
                  alert('Form Submitted');
              },
              error: function(data) {
                  alert('Form submission failed');
              }
           });
      }
  </script>
  ```

Comment: I tried your approach but for some reasons it didn't worked

Comment: I am getting this error on browser console `Uncaught TypeError: btn.addEventListener is not a function`

Comment: My bad, for jQuery you'd use `bind()` instead. I've updated the answer

Comment: Still doesn't works. Previous error is resolved but when I click the button nothings seems to happen.

Comment: Can you try adding a `console.log()` inside the `handleClick` function, before the AJAX call, to see if the listener is working?